# Typescript - Combobox Population

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app that contains a component called week-selector, it contains just a div with a heading and a `<select>` or dropdown.

I want to populate the dropdown with some team names however I am having an error on the `@Output()`, the error says:

> Generic Type 'EventEmitter requires 1 type argument(s)

My question: How to I populate the dropdown with teams?

This is my `week-selecotr.compnent.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import{EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

export class DropdownValue {
value:string;
label:string;

constructor(value:string,label:string) {
this.value = value;
this.label = label;
 }
}

@Component({
selector: 'dropdown',
template:
`
<form class = "ui small form segment">
<div id="WeekSubmission">
<h1> Please enter the week you are in: </h1>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#value of values" (click)="selectItem(value.value)">    {{value.label}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
  `
})

export class WeekSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
values:DropdownValue[];

@Output()
select:EventEmitter;

constructor() {
this.values = [ new DropdownValue('Team','Liverpool')];
this.select = new EventEmitter();
}

selectItem(value){
 this.select.emit(value)
}

ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to declare the "select" variable like:

```
@Output()select: EventEmitter<string>;
```

Instead of :

```
@Output()select: EventEmitter;
```

The type is required for the event emitter to signify the type of event value we are emitting. In your case it is a "string". So, I have declared it as :

```
@Output()select: EventEmitter<string>;
```

Hope this helps!